# Нужно ли тире перед предлогом «для»?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Наткнулся на такое предложение: *«Тойота — для уверенных и смелых»*.
Нужно ли здесь тире?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тире в таких (неполных) предложениях показывает, где необходимо сделать интонационную паузу.

> 4. Тире ставится в расчлененных (двучленных) заголовках, представляющих собой неполные безглагольные предложения, в которых имеются слова со значением субъекта/объекта действия, обстоятельства (отвечают на вопросы: «кто — чему?», «кто — куда?», «что — куда?», «что — как?», «что — где?» и т. п.): *Мастера искусств — молодёжи; **Туризм — для всех**; Отряды — в путь; Герои — рядом; Заботы и радости — пополам; Новые книги — нарасхват.*

[**Тире в неполном предложении**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93) (Розенталь)